error while performing dynamo.query(params); from lambda function
When performing body = await dynamo.query(params); from a lambda function, i am getting response as :

"statusCode": "400",
"body": "User: arn:aws:sts::891377999999:assumed-role/microserviceNodejsrole/microserviceNodejs1 is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:Query on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:891377999999:table/quizmaster because no identity-based policy allows the dynamodb:Query action",
"headers": {
"Content-Type": "application/json",
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "localhost"
}
}


Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.


"statusCode": "400", "body": "User: arn:aws:sts::891377999999:assumed-role/microserviceNodejsrole/microserviceNodejs1 is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:Query on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:891377999999:table/quizmaster because no identity-based policy allows the dynamodb:Query action", "headers": { "Content-Type": "application/json", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "localhost" } }

The exception is self explanatory, the role on your Lambda function arn:aws:sts::891377999999:assumed-role/microserviceNodejsrole/microserviceNodejs1 does not have Query permissions for table quizmaster. Add the following policy to the role:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "LhnngPolicy",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:Query"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:891377999999:table/quizmaster"
        }
    ]
}

